# How is it I am able to create a new instance of interface Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Tags: c#, com, office-interop, com-interop, dynamic-typing

According to the Word Interop documentation [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.aspx) is an interface, yet I am able to create a new instance of it as follows

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

There's also an example of this on [DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/word). It's normally not possible to create instances of an interface in C#, so how is it possible here? Is this a feature of COM or dynamic types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this is not C# interface but a COM interface. COM interfaces are represented in C# as interfaces with `ComImport` and `Guid` attributes.

```
[GuidAttribute("00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface Application : _Application, 
    ApplicationEvents4_Event
```